# Ruby-vips getting EXIF orientation

Tags: ruby, exif, vips

I'm attempting to get image EXIF data from the [ruby-vips gem](https://github.com/jcupitt/ruby-vips) but I keep receiving errors.  I've found [documentation from others](https://github.com/jcupitt/ruby-vips/issues/44) who have attempted to repair this issue and I've attempted their fixes with no success.

```
i=VIPS::Image.new("/home/eric/Pictures/golden-clouds-wallpaper.jpg")
i.get("exif-Orientation")
i.get("exif-ifd0-Orientation")
```

Both give errors:

```
VIPS error: vips_image_get: field "exif-Orientation" not found
VIPS error: vips_image_get: field "exif-ifd0-Orientation" not found
```

Ubuntu version 13.10

Vips version 7.28.5

ruby-vips 0.3.7

**Edit**

```
2.1.0 :001 > require 'rubygems' => false 
2.1.0 :002 > require 'vips' => true 
2.1.0 :003 > a = VIPS::Image.new('/home/eric/Pictures/devProfile.JPG') => #<VIPS::Image:0x00000001e4d7b0> 
2.1.0 :004 > a.get("exif-Orientation")
VIPS::Error: VIPS error: vips_image_get: field "exif-Orientation" not found

from (irb):4:in `get'
from (irb):4
from /home/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: For those looking to auto orient your image, take a look at [Rmagick#auto_orient](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#auto_orient), saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Thanks, yes Rmagick#auto_orient works well but this is a thread about the vips gem.  Previously, I used Rmagick but I had 10 times image processing times on it verses VIPS.  The trade-off is that the Vips Gem doesn't support auto_orient out of the box.

Comment: In hindsight, you're totally right, not sure why I posted this comment here. Maybe just as an alternative. Good to know how much more efficient VIPS is, though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the vips GUI, nip2, then try loading your JPEG image in that. Right-click on the thumbnail, select Header, and look at the fields displayed. You should see orientation in there.

I have Ubuntu 13.10 / vips-7.28.5 / ruby-vips 0.3.7 here and I see:

```
$ vips --version
vips-7.28.5-Sat Mar  9 18:46:42 UTC 2013
$ gem install ruby-vips
Fetching: ruby-vips-0.3.7.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ruby-vips-0.3.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ruby-vips-0.3.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-vips-0.3.7...
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'vips'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> a = VIPS::Image.new("pics/img_2522.jpg")
=> #<VIPS::Image:0x00000001a0e528>
irb(main):004:0> a.get("exif-Orientation")
=> "1 (Top-left, Short, 1 components, 2 bytes)"
irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with output that matches your answer. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you try with nip2, the vips GUI? It's in apt, just `sudo apt-get install nip2`. Load your image and confirm that vips can see the orientation field in your jpeg. Then in ruby-vips, try `VIPS::LIB_VERSION` and confirm that ruby-vips is picking up the correct libvips.

Comment: VIPS::LIB_VERSION = "7.28.5-Sat Mar  9 18:46:42 UTC 2013" matches my libvips version.

Comment: Here's my test image: http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/vips-7.8/doc/examples/img_2522.jpg can you see orientation in that? `a.exif?` should say if there's an EXIF block on the image, `a.exif` should return all the exif data as a binary string.

Comment: Interesting, your test image works but all of my test images fail.  I'm diving into the EXIF data now.

Comment: How strange. Could you post a test image somewhere? I'd like to investigate too.

Comment: All of the major image hosting services auto orient on upload. Let me see if I can find one that doesn't touch the EXIF data.